# Sell items with quantity 0 in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to allow users to make a purchase in WooCommerce with a product with quantity 0.

The process is as follows.

1. Employee creates and order on behalf of the customer
2. Customer goes to his accounts, sees order and presses edit.
3. He has 5 items in the cart and he can choose to keep all, keep some or keep none.
4. Min quantity 0 and max 1
5. If he decides to not keep something, he sets the quantity to 0

Problem is, if he sets quantity to 0, the product line disappears. I still need it in the cart, checkout and even in the order section.

I need this because we want to get feedback on each item line. I haven't been able to find anything that can keep the line present even if the quantity is 0.

If quantity is 0, price should also be 0, as you ain't paying for that.